# How can I take a good picture of the moon with a phone camera?

Tags: exposure, moon, night-photography

With my iPhone 8+, how do I take a picture of the moon without it looking like either a big white blurry blob or like I took a pic of a mirror with the flash on?

[image: moon]

Comment: Very definitely related if not directly relevant to how to do it with a phone camera: [How do I set the proper exposure for nighttime moon photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/459/how-do-i-set-the-proper-exposure-for-nighttime-moon-photos); tl;dr: you've massively overexposed the photo, the Moon is brighter than you think.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to take photo of moon with my mobile camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/114352/i-want-to-take-photo-of-moon-with-my-mobile-camera)

Comment: Also related: [How to take photos of planets with smartphone?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/99963/15871) and [Why are most smartphone cameras poor at capturing photos during the nighttime compared to DSLR cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/124814/15871)

Comment: Short of traveling on the second Starship flight around the Moon?